# Passing view with close button

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want the close button to be reusable so I created its own class so I can attach it to the views that need it. I want to just be able to pass the view that is attached to the view to the controller to close that view. It should be fairly simple and I would suspect that this is how many do it but I can't get it to work correctly. I get it to close the view but get the error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null 
I understand this to generally mean that the view isn't being destroyed but I thought this told it to destroy the view:

```
Ext.Viewport.remove(curView, true);
```

Here is what I believe to be the pertinent code
Controller:

```
closeView: function(btn, e,opts){             
            var curView = btn.getParent().getParent();
           console.log('From btn: ' + curView + ',' + opts);             
           Ext.Viewport.remove(curView, true);}
```

View:

```
Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.view.DetailView',{
      extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
      requires: ['Ext.Toolbar', 'Ext.tab.Panel', 'Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.field.Select'],
      model: ['SenchaFirstApp.model.Details', 'SenchaFirstApp.model.SiteInfo'],
      alias: 'widget.detailview',
//      xtype: 'tabpanel',


    config:
    {
          scrollable: true,
          width: 1500,
          height: 800,
    //      fullscreen: true,
          layout: {type: 'card', animation:{type: 'flip'}},
          centered: true,
          border: 10,
          tabBar: {
              docked: 'top',
          }, 
          formParams: {
        },
      items: 
      [
       {
         //Tab bar 
         xtype:  'tbar',
         title: 'Details View',
             items: [
            {
              xtype: 'closebtn',
              id: 'detailsBtn',
              sourceForm: this
            }]
        },
        {
            title: 'Equipment Monitor',        //first tab
            xtype: 'monitor',
        },                        
        {
            title: 'Site Information',            //second tab
            xtype: 'siteinfo',
        }
    ]                    
} //End Config
```

I tried to use

```
Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem, true)
```

but that also didn't work. I suspect that has to do with how I created that view maybe. I'm new to Sencha so there could be many things I'm doing wrong so I appreciate the help.

I forgot to mention that, after closing the tab panel, I can't open it again without refreshing which again I'm sure is due to the view not being destroyed

Comment: Try using the destroy method like curView.destroy();

Comment: @blessenm Thanks for the response but that doesn't work either. I get this error

Comment: 'Object [object Window] has no method 'destroy' ' The 'true' property is suppose to destroy the view in the code that I have so I think I'm not passing the view correctly with the button which is what I need to understand how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem was using id's. I thought that I took them out but I guess not. I took the id's out and used alias's and got it working. I'm still not figuring out how to pass the view attached to the button but now

```
Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem, true)
```

is working. The true property tells it to destroy the view after removing it.